# Fixed Point Summary

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

I know someone has given me resources for this before but I can't seem to find them...
Would someone please summarize stable vs unstable, attracting vs repelling, and node, saddle,etc fixed points? I am getting confused about classifying the fixed points because the information in my book is kind of spread all over, not compiled in a table or something.
Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Amzoti "an introduction to dynamical systems: continuous and discrete" I find this textbook really difficult to work with

Comment: oh sorry, yes it's Robinson

Comment: I really appreciate this, thank you so much! With all of the help on this website this class seems manageable, but just relying on the book and my professor....this class has been a nightmare. This book is really hard for me to use

Answer (score 0):

We have two type of stable fixed point: asymptotically stable and naturally stable.If the fixed is none of them it's an unstable.
x is a naturally stable equilibrium (or fixedpoint) if for every neighborhood U of x there is a neighborhood V⊆U of x such that every solution x(t) starting in V (x(0)∈V) remains in U for all t≥0. Notice that x(t) need not approach x.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).